# Joomla: How to get the URL of an associated menu item (Multilingual / from current page)

Tags: php, joomla, menu, multilingual

i want to manually add a hreflang-attribute to the HTML-Head of a page.

I'm using Joomla 3.4.8 + SEBLOD component for a multilingual site. If I associate menu items of different languages, usually a "link-tag" and a "hreflang-attribute" are added to the head to make the relationship between the menu items visible for search engines.

For some reason, this tag is not added, if I'm in a list-and-search-view of the Seblod component. That's why I manually want to write the missing tags to the head.

I know how to add meta information to the head and how to get the ID of the current menu item, **but I can't figure out how to get the ID (or SEO-friendly URL) of the associated menu items** of my current page.

Any ideas?

I hope I described myself well...
Thanks in advance!

Example:
The menu item of the current page is in german language. It is associated / connected with a menu item in english language (which is showing the english version of the current page). What I need is the SEF-URL of the english menu item.

Comment: OK, after a while I found an answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948218/joomla-find-all-translations-of-a-menu-item

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to query the active menu so you get all of the variables for the menu. The code below should return the current active route for the menu:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu   = $app->getMenu()->getActive();

$sefUrl = $menu->route;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($menu);
echo '</pre>';

echo $sefUrl;

//HERE IS THE PHP TO SET A META DYNAMICALLY IF YOU NEED IT AS WELL
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMetaData( 'tag-name', 'tag-content', true );
```

If the route that is being returned is not the correct route that matches your page you can check to see if the link attribute includes index.php using strpos and then concatenate that and the menu id to run through JRoute for an SEF url as well like so:

```
if(strpos($menu-Link,'index.php?') !== false){
    $sefUrl = JRoute::_($menu->link.'&Itemid='.$menu->id);
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi Terry,
thanks for your reply. You describe how to get the SEF-URL of the current menu item, but what I need, are the SEF-friendly URLs of all menuitems, which are linked / associated to the current one for multilanguage purposes.


Example: The current menu item is in german language, it is associated with another one in englisch language. What I can't figure out is how to get the SEF-URL of the english menu item.

Comment: How are they associated? Do the share a common article name?

Comment: If you know how the articles are related you should be able to query the Itemid of the menu item for that specific article and then get the sef url in the same manner I have here. I can probably give you a code example if you can tell me how you linked them.

If you have multiple menus for each language in the backend, with the same article titles in each menu like this:

English Menu -> Article 1
German Menu -> Article 1

The in the database you can query the link and Itemid and then use the menu_type and title as the where clause filters.

Comment: I try to describe my setup with the following example. I hope this makes sense.

I've got two menus:
*A "German Menu" with menu item "Kontakte". The menuitem is associated with "Contacts".
*An "Englisch Menu" with menu item "Contacts". The menuitem is associated with "Contacts".

Both items are linked to a Seblod-List and Search view, not a standard-article. The associtation is configured in the menu items options.

Comment: If I look at the values of the menuitem object ($menu in your code) I don't see any reference to the associated menuitem.
As far as I can see, the connection is saved in the "__associations"-table of the database, but I don't know how to handle the saved data.

Comment: I would have to install seblod to check out how their table is setup. Chances are that the associations table probably references the item ids of each menu item, you could cross reference those IDs with the #__menu table and then JRoute the links together like my example.

Comment: Hi Terry, you don't need seblod, because the associations are stored the same way on a fresh "joomla only" installation. But while I looked at it, I realized that the md5-generated keys are used to reference the items. I was "blind", because I was always looking for an ID or something like that. But the way it is done (the keys) it is possible to create associations with more than one language.
Thanks for your time and help!